# show rest api json response like textbox autopopulate using angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json, rest, api

I'm accessing address lookup rest API service - JSON response. I want to show my JSON response like auto-dropdown list. Rest service result has 5 JSON array list for all my search but in my below code that JSON result again filter based on the value entered in the textbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/3etbtfwL/230/

Test Case# 
1) Entered 'google' in textbox rest service returns 5 JSON array list is showing auto populate result in textbox like this - **Pass**

[image]

2) Entered 'google drive' in textbox - rest service actually returns 5 JSON array list correctly but no value is showing in the text box auto-populate list - **Fail**
(Reason - My entered value is not matched with JSON return list value)

[image]

How to show all the value which is return from JSON result like textbox auto-populate.

**Angular code**

```
var app = angular.module('httpApp', []);

app.controller('httpAppCtrlr', function ($scope, $http) {

     $scope.AddressLookup = function (address) {                 
     $http.get('http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest?text=' + address + '&f=json')
        .then(function (results) {
           $scope.items = results.data.suggestions;        
    });
    }
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div data-ng-app='httpApp' data-ng-controller='httpAppCtrlr'>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="item.text" list="comicstitle" 
               placeholder="Address Lookup"
               ng-change="AddressLookup(item.text)"
               >
        <datalist id="comicstitle">
            <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.text}}" >{{item.text}}</option>
        </datalist>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you getting response regarding your text you entered **google drive**, if so then use $timeout inside your controller

```
var app = angular.module('httpApp', []);



 app.controller('httpAppCtrlr', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.AddressLookup = function (address) {                 
 $http.get('http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest?text=' + address + '&f=json')
    .then(function (results) {
       $timeout(function() {
         $scope.items = results.data.suggestions;
       })        
    });
  }
 });
```

Comment: Yes I’m getting response for my search but that JSON result was not showing in my text box auto populate list. Check this link for reference - http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest?text=google%20drive&f=json

Comment: can you show me the directive you are using in this code

Comment: I’m not using directives. Plz check attached jsfiddle for more source code details.

Comment: i saw your fiddle but i ain't able to understand what is  <datalist> in your html, there could be a reason that it is a directive

Comment: <datalist> Is a html tag. It generates the auto populate value based on value entered in associated text box. I feel when I enter google drive - JSON result has value but not same word ‘google drive’ since Data not listing. I believe we have to use some other control to show likeauto populate list.